Runtime exception error on Google play console for AutoTranslateSettingJobService settings and same source and destination for locale
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Source and target locales are the same
  at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage (JobServiceEngine.java:118)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7918)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Source and target locales are the same
  at mnb.bw
  at exp.a (PG:9)
  at exq.b
  at com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.translate.settings.jobservice.AutoTranslateSettingJobService.onStopJob (PG:5)
  at android.app.job.JobService$1.onStopJob (JobService.java:73)
  at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage (JobServiceEngine.java:114)

Here is the screenshot
I need a solution so that I can publish the app and get it to the hands of users by getting it out of the development process.
